# Recursion and return a function

Tags: c#, javascript

I have the following code in JavaScript and I would like to write the same in C#. I don't know how to do recursion and returning a function together.

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

I thought this would work but it isn't.

```
public static Func<int, string, string> findSequence(int goal)
{
    var find = new Func<int, string, string>(start, history => {
        if (start == goal)
            return history;
        else if (start > goal)
            return null;
        else
            return (find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
                     find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)"));
        });

        return find;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new function inside the function? You just have to call the same function to recurse.

Comment: Your javascript function returns string. So your C# findSequence should also return string. Also you forgot to call find(1, "1") in the end of findSequence function.

Comment: Does that compile? It shouldn't (no VS to test sorry). The `find` Func is used inside its own body before it is declared. First declare it then it will be available in its implementation.: `Func<int, string, string> find = null; find = (start, history) => { if (...){...} else {...} return find(1, "1"); };`

Comment: Please describe the goal of this function. I do not get the `||`operator usage in the returned string construction.

Comment: the program worked. the mistakes were that explained by Konstantin also instead of "||", I used "??".